# SenTransaction can't send Ether to a contract address

Tags: truffle, openzeppelin

I am using `openzeppelin`, `Ganache` and `truffle`, here's a very simple smart contract for fundraising:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;


import 'openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol';


contract PrivateSale is Crowdsale {


  constructor(address wallet,
              ERC20 token,
              uint256 rate,
              )
              public
              Crowdsale(rate, wallet, token) {
  }

}
```

After migrate this contract, I tried to send Ether from `truffle console`:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
  from: web3.eth.accounts[2], 
  value: web3.toWei(10), 
  to: PrivateSale.address
})
```

But there's a exception here:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
    at Eth.send [as sendTransaction] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/method.js:145:1)
    at RequestManager.send (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:61:1)
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)
```

I also tried to transfer from account to account, it works fine, but only not work for contracts.

Here's how I deploy it:

```
const DemoToken = artifacts.require("DemoToken");
const PrivateSale = artifacts.require("PrivateSale");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  const fundWallet = '0x629***'
  const rate = 1500

  deployer.deploy(PrivateSale,
                  fundWallet,
                  DemoToken.address,
                  rate);
};
```

Comment: Is `web3.eth.accounts[2]` whitelisted?

Comment: thanks, @smarx, I removed WhiteListedCrowsale, the problem still there.

Comment: Is it after `openingTime` and before `closingTime`? What's `softcap`? There's a lot of code to read/debug here. I'd suggest simplifying the code as much as possible until it works (or the bug is obvious), and then build back up.

Comment: @smarx, I tried to use the simplest Crowdsale, but the result is the same :/

Comment: What's the `ERC20` token you're passing to the constructor? Have you transferred enough tokens to the `Crowdsale` contract to cover the purchase? (Maybe just show the rest of your code.)

Comment: @smarx, thanks so much, I added how I deploy this contract, and this is all of the code.

Comment: It looks to me like you're not transferring any tokens to the `PrivateSale` contract.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78617/discussion-between-mrroy-and-smarx).

Answer (score 0):

OK, silly mistake, it turns out I need to transfer my DemoToken to the contract first.